# Must consteval constructor initialize all data members?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, consteval

In the next program `struct B` has immediate `consteval` default constructor, which does not initialize `i` field. Then this constructor is used to make a temporary and its `i` field remains untouched:

```
struct B {
    bool b = true;
    int i;
    consteval B() {}
};

static_assert( B{}.b );
```

Clang and MSVC are fine with it. But GCC complains:

```
 error: 'B{true}' is not a constant expression
    7 | static_assert( B{}.b );
      |                  ^
error: 'B()' is not a constant expression because it refers to an incompletely initialized variable
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x4n6ezrhT

Which compiler is right here?

*Update:*

I reported this issue to GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104512
And it was closed with the explanation

> This gives the hint that both MSVC and clang are incorrect really. EDG also implements correctly static_assert not being an immediate function context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From cppreference's [consteval specifier (since C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval):

> The consteval specifier declares a function or function template to be
> an immediate function,
> ...
> An immediate function is a constexpr function, and **must satisfy the
> requirements applicable to constexpr functions or constexpr
> constructors**, as the case may be.

And if we go to cppreference's [constexpr specifier (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> A constexpr function must satisfy the following requirements:
> ...
> A constexpr constructor whose function body is not =delete; must satisfy the following additional requirements:
> ...
> for the constructor of a class or struct, every base class sub-object
> and **every non-variant non-static data member must be initialized.**

However, as @user17732522 accurately pointed out in a comment below, this last requirement applies only **until C++20**.

So I would say `i` doesn't need to be initialized in this case (Clang/MSVC are correct, gcc is wrong).

Comment: The initialization requirement applies only before C++20.

Comment: @user17732522 True. I hadn't noticed. I'll update my answer. Many thanks for the comment.